# Unable to access props of React component inside styled.div component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am relatively new to React (after coming over from Angular) and am having trouble with trying to access a property of a styled component when passed into it.

I get this error:

```
/src/chat/Container.js
  Line 115:5:  'cssOverrides' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Here is my App.js component:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const cssOverrides = useSelector((state) => state.cssOverrides.ChatWindow)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {isOpen ? (
        <ChatContainer setIsOpen={setIsOpen} cssOverrides={cssOverrides} />
      ) : (
        <LauncherContainer setIsOpen={setIsOpen} cssOverrides={cssOverrides} />
      )}
    </Provider>
  );
```

And one of the child components:

```
export default function Container({ setIsOpen, cssOverrides }) {
  const [isClosing, setIsClosing] = React.useState(false);
```

And the styled component (where I am trying to usee the css string passed into it as a property)

```
const Launcher = styled.div`
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 5px 40px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 38px;
  width: 375px;
  right: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  ${cssOverrides}
  animation: ${({ isClosing }) =>
    isClosing
      ? css`
          ${slideDown} ${CLOSING_DURATION}ms
        `
      : css`
          ${slideUp} 200ms
        `};
`;
```

Can anyone offer any advice as to why this error is happening? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer. I forgot to add the property cssOverrides to the Launcher component instance in the JSX

```
<Launcher isClosing={isClosing} cssOverrides={cssOverrides}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property as a callback.

```
// Good
const Launcher = styled.div`
  ${({ cssOverrides }) => cssOverrides}
`;


// Bad
// Looks for cssOverrides value in the outer scope, where its not defined.
const Launcher = styled.div`
  ${cssOverrides}
`;

// Usually such syntax used for css blocks
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

// Not passed as prop, located in the outer scope
const cssOverrides = css`
   background-color: blue;
`

// Good
const Launcher = styled.div`
  ${cssOverrides}
`;
```

Comment: Great thanks. The value is coming through as undefined when I try and access it via the literal still though. When I check inside the funciton the value is being shown correctly.

Comment: Please show reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and not snippets of code. Can you recreate the problem in a sandbox? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: I've added more relevant code to the original question. I hard coded the value into App.js to ensure this problem is isolated. Does that offer any more insight?

Comment: No, I don't see any edits. Why not creating a minimal example in sandbox? It sure will solve the problem.